# Regex validation rules

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm writing a database backup function as part of my school project.

I need to write a regex rule so the database backup name can only contain legal characters.

By 'legal' I mean a string that doesn't contain ANY symbols or spaces. Only letters from the alphabet and numbers.

An example of a valid string would be `'31Jan2012'` or `'63927jkdfjsdbjk623'` or `'hello123backup'`.

Here's my JS code so far:

```
    // Check if the input box contains the charactes a-z, A-Z ,or 0-9 with a regular expression.

    function checkIfContainsNumbersOrCharacters(elem, errorMessage){
        var regexRule = new RegExp("^[\w]+$");
        if(regexRule.test( $(elem).val() ) ){ 
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
    }


//call the function

checkIfContainsNumbersOrCharacters("#backup-name", "Input can only contain the characters a-z or 0-9.");
```

I've never really used regular expressions before though, however after a quick bit of googling i found [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) tool, from which I wrote the following regex rule:

```
^[\w]+$
```

^ = start of string

[/w] = a-z/A-Z/0-9

'+' = characters after the string.

When running my function, the whatever string I input seems to return false :( is my code wrong? or am I not using regex rules correctly?

Comment: I tried `/^[\w]+$/.test("ads123")` in my JS console, and it works, that is, returns `true` as it should.

Comment: `new Regexp("[regexp-goes-here]", "[modifiers]")` and `/[regexp-goes-here]/[modifiers]` are equivalent. Do note the use of quotes in the former one, and absence in the latter.

Comment: A slightly more correct explanation for the `+` would be "match the previous token (i.e. `\w`) 1 or more times". But the code should work, from what I can see.

Comment: All your replies are too good to vote on, so I up-voted you all. A massive thanks to everyone who replied/ commented on this question, I've learnt a lot and the problem is now solved :)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the regex as a string parameter to the RegExp constructor, you need to escape it. Both

```
var regexRule = new RegExp("^[\\w]+$");
```

...and...

```
var regexRule = new RegExp(/^[\w]+$/);
```

will work.

Keep in mind though, that client side validation for database data will never be enough, as the validation is easily bypassed by disabling javascript in the browser, and invalid/malicious data can reach your DB. You need to validate the data on the server side, but preventing the request with invalid data, but validating client side is good practice.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer. You'd have to escape the string to make it work, though.

Comment: No need for `new RegExp` if you are using a literal. `/asdf/` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `\w` is a synonym for [[:alnum:]], which matches a single character of the alnum class.  Note that using character classes means that you may match characters that are not part of the ASCII character encoding, which may or may not be what you want.  If what you really intend to match is `[0-9A-Za-z]`, then that's what you should use.

Comment: `\w` and `[\w]` in this case are absolutely equivalent - the brackets aren't needed, but it'll make no difference to the result.

Comment: Is that a JavaScript thing, then?  In other environments, characters inside a range lose their specialness.  Or is `[\w]` considered a character class, equivalent to `[:print:]` ?

Comment: `[\w]` does the same in every regex dialect - javascript, .NET, Python, Perl, Ruby, XPath etc. Except that `\w` means different things depending on whether the dialect is unicode-aware. The brackets make no difference.

Comment: I note that \w is not included in re_format(3), and does not appear to be part of the POSIX 1003.2 definition of regular expressions, though I see from the grep(1) man page that \w is a synonym for the [[:alnum:]] character class.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The two exceptions would be the basic regular expression dialects of GNU and POSIX. The extended dialects for both support it. But then, "+" isn't supported in the BRE dialects either, and would also be matched literally.

Comment: Updated my answer to contain other, more correct and useful information. Thanks for your pointers.  :)

Comment: Another downvote neutralized by my upvote (I've yet to downvote an answer on SO) - mostly +1 for noting that allowing non-ASCII chars may not be intended. Of course, if Javascript ever gets to support unicode for `\w`, for backwards compatibility, it will probably add a `/u` modifier like PCRE. Still, nice to be aware of, because most aren't.

Answer (score 2):

It can be simpler. This works:

```
function checkValid(name) {
  return /^\w+$/.test(name);
}
```

`/^\w+$/` is the literal notation for `new RegExp()`. Since the `.test` function returns a boolean, you only need to return its result. This also reads better than `new RegExp("^\\w+$")`, and you're less likely to goof up (thanks @x3ro for pointing out the need for two backslashes in strings).

Comment: -1 For saying that the regex was fine, because there is an error in it

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, that when writing `\w` inside a string, you escape the `w`, and the resulting regular expression looks like this: `^[w]+$`, containing the `w` as a literal character. When creating a regular expression with a string argument passed to the `RegExp` constructor, you need to escape the backslash, like so: `new RegExp("^[\\w]+$")`, which will create the regex you want.

There is a way to avoid that, using the shorthand notation provided by JavaScript: `var regex = /^[\w]+$/;` which does not need any extra escaping.

Comment: +1 for me missing that, even if I explained it in another post only a few hours ago. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the official spec: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html but it's not very easily converted to a regular expression. Just a regular expression won't do it as there are also [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Why not just put it in the query (don't forget to escape it properly) and let MySQL give you an error? There might for instance be a bug in the MySQL version you're using, and even though your check is correct, MySQL might still refuse.

Comment: -1 Putting stuff in a MySQL query that is not validated / cleaned does not seem to be a good idea to me.

Comment: Sure it does, just make sure you escape it properly.

Comment: Fair enough. Taking back my `-1` and adding a notice to not forget to escape properly :)